# Using OData with model inheritance cause missing property error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, odata

I got this error in my OData with asp.net core implementation during the runtime :The EDM instance of type '[XXX.Asset Nullable=True]' is missing the property 'externalId'.

The problem appear when I try to access the odata endpoint with the expand query: "/odata/v1/precinct?$expand=assets". It seems happening because I put the "ExternalId" property in my base class, its not happening if I put that property in the "Asset".

Below is my recent codes:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
}
public class Precinct : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

}
public class Asset : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my model configuration for ODATA

```
public class AssetModelConfiguration : IModelConfiguration
{
    public void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder, ApiVersion apiVersion)
    {
        var org = builder.EntitySet<Asset>("asset").EntityType;
        org.HasKey(x => x.ExternalId);
        org.Ignore(x => x.Id);

    }
}
```

The strange thing is if I put that ExternalId in "Asset" class, it is working. Id property is the primary key while the "ExternalId" is marked as AlternateKey in the DBModel configuration.

am I missing something in my odata configuration? already tried many things but couldn't find a good answer. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've never used this myself but what happens if you capitalize the string "asset" like so: `var org = builder.EntitySet<Asset>("Asset").EntityType;`? Again, I don't know what EntitySet does under the hood so forgive me if it's a silly suggestion.

Comment: have you fixed this @ocky saktya